# Matching an Optional Capture Group

Tags: .net, regex

I want to match an xml element and create a group for an optional attribute. If the attribute does not exist then i'm going to perform some other action. For example i have

```
<customer display="no">
```

I want to match on the customer element but the display attribute might not exist. In code i was going to check to see if that capture group is empty and if so perform some custom logic.

so the regex i have is

```
<customer.*(display="yes|no").*?>
```

That matches the element ok when it has the attribute but how can i make the group optional so i can check to see if the element was included?

Comment: Don't use regex for XML parsing!!! According to tags you are using .NET. In .NET we have XmlReader, XmlDocument and XDocument -- standard classes to work with XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put a question mark after the group, the same as any other optional component of a regex. You will also have to make the first `.*` lazy (by adding `?`) if you do this, otherwise it will consume the whole line.

So you should have something like this:

```
<customer.*?(display="yes|no")?.*?>
```

Also note that `(display="yes|no")` probably doesn't match what you want it to: it matches `display="yes` or `no"` *not* `display="yes"` or `display="no"`. I suspect you want `(display="(?:yes|no)")` instead.

Comment: yeah i just figured out the problem was the first .* was greedy, it should have been .*?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
<customer.*?(display="(?:yes|no)").*?>
```

explain:

> ***`?`***
>
> Matches the previous element zero or one time.
>
> ***`*?`***
>
> Matches the previous element zero or more times, but as few times as possible.
>
> ***`(?: subexpression)`***
>
> Defines a noncapturing group.

Comment: I tried that but it was making the match greedy, but i just figured out that was because of the first any character match was greedy. <customer.* should have been <customer.*? so i ended up with <customer.*?(display="yes|no")?.*?>